# How to fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm having issue trying to copy an array and I've looked but can't figure out how to get rid of my outofboundsexception. Help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class project {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int [] array = {1, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 10, 2};
   int [] sortedArray = {array.length};
   System.arraycopy(array, 0, sortedArray, 0, array.length);
   Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
   System.out.println("Before the sort: " + Arrays.toString(array) );
   System.out.println("After the sort: " +  Arrays.toString(sortedArray) );

}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
int [] sortedArray = {array.length};
```

This does not create an array of length `array.length`. This creates a new array with one element.

Instead, create a new array like this (aka: no initializer)

```
int[] sortedArray = new int[array.length];
```